# R Server on Azure

Tags: r, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-machine-learning-service

I need to execute R code as webservice, so I tried MLS and it works ok.
The problem is that the packages are too old, and I need functions that are not implemented on old packages.
I asked Microsoft support about it, and they have no data up upgrade it, and the new packages require a upgrade of it.

How can I do that using other resources, like webapi instead of MLS?
All solutions I found requires R installed on machine, which is a problem for create an azure webapp, function, or API.
I need an endpoint for forecast on-demand.

Comment: Perhaps Azure Databricks may be a viable choice?

Comment: The problem of Databrick is that i need on-demand service.

Comment: You should be able to do that with Databricks by running a notebook as an on-demand job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to execute R on Azure functions.
the solutions is copy R-Portable in
https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/
unzip it using powershell and create a process on function code. In my case i used the code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\home\site\tools\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\";
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\home\site\tools\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-e \"print('Hello world')\"";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.Start();
            string outputt = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

On your script you can access csv files or write, and after on function read and return that file.